# Good practices to test piece of code with object instantiation

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, kotlin

Is there any guidelines (or best practices) which puts in order the following?

I have the following method to test:

```
fun findProfileByPersonalInfo(personInfo: PersonalInfo): Profile? {
    localProfileRepository.findByPersonalInfo(personalInfo)?.let {
        return it
    }
    val searchParams = RemoteProfileSearchParameters()
    //... Some mapping from personalInfo to searchParams
    remoteProfileRepository.findRemoteProfile(searchParams)?.let {
        val profile = profileFactory.create(remoteProfile)
        return save(profile)
    }
    return null
}
```

When I came to writing unit tests for this function I realized that:

1. It is easy and convenient to test line `val profile = profileFactory.create(remoteProfile)` because I can mock the result of this call and test the mapping from `remoteProfile` to `profile` somewhere else separately. Having this, if I change the logic of mapping I won't break my test for `findProfileByPersonalInfo`, which is good.
2. And vice versa, it feels not right and difficult to maintain the test if the logic of mapping from `personalInfo` to `searchParams` belongs to `findProfileByPersonalInfo`.

The questions are:

1. Is it ok to (almost) always move instantiation logic from function under test to make it more testable and maintainable? Undoubtedly, the exception for this is functions whose only responsibility is to instantiate objects.
2. Isn't it too much to create a some type of factory for each object that falls under the situation described above? It seems like the overall design of the system suffers because of this.

Any references to best practices or discussions are very appreciated. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

1. That's a bit broad, in general you want methods to not do too much and move reusable portions of code to a separate method. Based on the limited context you show, in this case I would most certainly move the instantiation out, both for testability and readability reasons.
2. You don't always need a fullblown factory, depending on context a simple constructor `RemoteProfileSearchParameters(personInfo: PersonalInfo)` might be the most sensible here. Depending on complexity, this might be refactored to a factory method or an actual factory object, but generally this won't be your first goto.

Comment: Thanks for you response, I generally agree with you. But how do you test the instantiation logic in case of constructor (even it is possible to mock constructors with some frameworks, it is rather a "no no")?

Comment: You just instantiate an object of said class and confirm the behavior of this object is as expected based on the input provided in the constructor.

Mocking wouldn't make sense since you'd be mocking the very thing you want to test and thus be testing your mock.

If calling the constructor in the tests is not possible eg due to external dependencies then you'll want to inject these dependencies in your main code and mock those away in the tests.